# determinant format in Cramer's rule in Tom Apostol's Calculus, vol $1$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Sorry for asking the book specific question, but I hope it's not only me who is finding the book very useful, and for some reason got somewhat surprised when seeing how he used it when explaining the Cramer's rule.

In the section $13.12$ he introduced $3x3$ determinant for computing $A \cdot B \times C$ as

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
c_1 & c_2 & c_3
\end{vmatrix}
$$

where $A = (a_1, a_2, a_3)$, and $B, C$ are analogously defined. That, I think, suggests that each row contains components of one vector.

However, in the section $13.13$ he says that for the system $xA + yB + zC = D$, the determinant used to calculate $A \cdot B \times C$ is:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3
\end{vmatrix}
$$

I understand that both orderings give us exactly the same scalar value, but I am still wondering if there a reason he decided to transpose the determinant?

Thanks!

Comment: It is probably because of the typographical presentation of the coefficients in the system of linear equations
$$
a_1 x + b_1 y + c_1 z = d_1, \\
a_2 x + b_2 y + c_2 z = d_2, \\
a_3 x + b_3 y + c_3 z = d_3.
$$

Comment: A plausible reason is that the system may be written $$\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & b_1 & c_1 \\
a_2 & b_2 & c_2 \\
a_3 & b_3 & c_3
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

Comment: I agree, but why would he not be consistent, and stick to the column-wise format in the earlier example as well? I might have to wait for volume $2$ where he's going into the determinants in more detail...